# What is the word for **to agree without questions**?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I felt that maybe there is an alternate and concise way of saying **She agreed to follow without asking questions** in one(or two) word(s) ?

Comment: You can "*agree unconditionally*".

Comment: 'Agreed unquestioningly'.

Comment: 'Agreed faithfully' or 'as a matter of faith'

Comment: *accepted the instructions*

Comment: She obeyed and followed [, goose-stepping all the way].

Comment: The problem with all the above comments is that they either miss the part "without asking questions" or have the word agree and a synonym for without questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider ***acquiesce***.

> to accept, agree, or allow something to happen by staying silent or by not arguing [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce)

The verb *acquiesce* comes from the Latin word *acquiescere*, meaning “to rest.” If you “rest” or become passive in the face of something to which you object, you are giving tacit agreement, you acquiesce.

Comment: But you can acquiesce to something that you questioned and still don't agree with. "Go sit in the corner!" "Do I have a choice about this?" "No!" "Then I shall acquiesce to your command". Questioning is not ruled out

Comment: @Jim: Yes, I gave that detail also. But even you have a reluctance or an objection, you can still acquiesce without questioning. You stay silent. So it depends on the context. Your answer "unquestioningly" is good but I thought OP would prefer a verb.

Comment: That is the essence of my point. How can a word that gives no information by itself on whether or not questions were asked be used (as a general term) to express the idea that no questions were asked?

Comment: The OP asks how to express the idea of agreeing or accepting without questioning in one or two words. If it is sometimes necessary to write "acquiesce without questioning" then the term "acquiesce" obviously does not carry the required meaning to express the primary "without questioning" part and only suits to express the secondary "agree" or "accept" part of the desired idea. If it were a viable word, then "acquiesce without questioning" would be redundant in any context

Comment: In my opinion, "acquiesce" covers agreeing without questioning and without arguing. It is in the definition also. OP could give  a more detailed context as well.

Comment: This makes maximum sense to me, I am going to accept this as answer. "I asked her to not reveal our last excursion, she acquiesced."

Comment: This isn't completely satisfactory to me. I'm looking for a word that does not imply the person's feeling about it, but just that the person agrees without thinking about it at all.

Answer (score 2):

> *She [concurred](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concur).*

It doesn't necessarily specify *without question* but is used in situations where brevity is desired to agree with a statement.

Another word is [acquiesce](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquiesce) which means agree without protest.

Comment: I'm giving a minus one because, as you pointed out, "concurred" doesn't necessitate that no questions are asked. However, the question here specifically asks for words meaning "without asking questions".

Comment: @Jim Considering it's often used in the context, and rarely as in the "concur, but also I have questions", I'll just leave it here anyway.

Comment: "At first she didn't understand his point, so she asked for clarification. Once given, she concurred". Notice that concurred only indicates agreement or acceptance, not a lack of questions. It does not even connotatively imply a lack of questions, just that agreement is present

Comment: @Jim I think the problem is in the OQ. Once agreement is reached, question time is over.

Comment: True, but I think without questions means none in the time between proposal of an idea and the agreement of it. At least, that's how I would read it.

Comment: You know what? I wouldn't use this simply because in American law, a "concurrence" is a case where a judge on a panel agrees with the other judges in the result of their decision, but does not fully endorse their reasoning. I my mind, the word implies somewhat weak agreement, and (to me, at least) implies that there may indeed be some questions in that party's mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Unquestioningly** seems to fit your request; it's one word that means exactly what you describe. In some contexts, **blindly** might also be appropriate.

> She agreed to follow, *unquestioningly*.
>
> She agreed to follow, *blindly*.

While neither of those words indicate the presence of agreement or acceptance on their own, they do express the lack of questions. Depending on context, you could do away with the "agree" part and say something like:

> She followed *unquestioningly*

However, if, say, the following is yet to come and the unquestioned act is actually just the agreement, then *agreed unquestioningly* is about as close as it gets without introducing positive/negative connotations or without introducing the possibility for questions.

If the context is about accepting or believing something, the idiom **take at face value** might be appropriate, but it doesn't fit the one or two word criterion.

Comment: In what way does this include agreement?

Answer (score 1):

"She agreed *unequivocally*" is another way that you could say the same thing as the (helpful) suggestions above.

Answer (score 1):

The (dead?) metaphor **rubber-stamp** is often used in situations like this.

> *rubber-stamp* (verb) [with object] Approve automatically without proper
>   consideration: [P]arliament merely rubber-stamped the decisions of the
>   party

{[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rubber-stamp)}

Answer (score 0):

Agreed [wholeheartedly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wholehearted) might be the word:

> marked by complete earnest commitment; free from all reserve or hesitation. "gave the proposal *wholehearted* approval"

Comment: Can I point out that wholeheartedly does not indicate that no questions are asked. It indicates that complete support or favour is given. One can ask questions and get more information and then still do something wholeheartedly. "Why should I do what you ask?" "Because reasons." "Good point. I'll wholeheartedly comply."

Answer (score -2):

I think "she agreed doubtlessly"  or "she agreed in a servile manner" fits what you are looking for.